# Less : blank page on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, less, cdn

I'm using Less to generate the css by calling this cdn in my head.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

When I'm going on a computer the page is perfectly generated, but when I check it on a mobile device it returns a completly blank page without any error or any message. I know that the problem comes from Less because when I delete the link to less it works. So after several searches on stackoverflow I found a answer of someone who told me to add this script before I call the cdn of Less.

```
<script>less = { async: true };</script>
```

Which worked in the sense that it displayed the whole webpage but without any css. So it is not really a solution to my problem

Does someone know what to do ?
Thank you

Comment: You should consider compiling the less to css on the server instead of sending less to each client.

Comment: feed the browser compiled css which is way better than asking your browser to understand what it natively doesn't with the help of a library on runtime. :)

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: @FabulousCo A good place to start: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: They are telling to take the cdn... the other options don't work